# How can two scripts use the same port at the same time?

Tags: php, networking, port, fsockopen

I'm trying to set up a "server" script in PHP, which should run for a limited amount of time in the background. But multiple instances of this script may run at the same time. Unfortunately fsockopen() doesn't let me use the same port at the same time by two different scripts, so others fail in error :(

Is there any way around this?

Comment: what's the goal  ? what do you want to build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesnot support *multi-threading*, but there are alternatives to it, not the best but in slang word- "workable".

And to listen on specific port using ***php***, Use `socket_listen`, `socket_bind`, `socket_create`, etc., functions of php, you may have a look on `stream_select` functions too... if that helps.

Recommended page  ***[Parallel processing in PHP](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254)***

Answer (score 2):

**fsockopen**  is for client socket and you cannot start a server to listen on specific port with **fsockopen**